# Submit one form leads to Submit of another : 3 Html forms in a Page

Tags: php, jquery, html, css, form-submit

** Scenario:**

- I have 3 forms in one page (settings)
- When I click on any button, the other two forms are set to hide by jquery

[image]

** Problem:**

- When I submit the second form or the third, the first form is been submitted only although all the forms name are different
- the other two forms do not even respond to jquery and to the preventDefault method

**first form submit code :**

```
$('form[name=noteForm]').submit(function(e){    
    var postData = $(this).serialize();
    $.ajax({
        url: baseURL + "admin/Settings/ChangeNotificationSettings",
        type:'post',
        data:postData,
        success:function(data){
            SetNotificationModal('settings successfully updated');
        } ,
        error:function(data){
            alert(data);
        }
    });
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

**second form :**

```
$('form[name=socialMedia]').submit(function(evt){
        evt.preventDefault();
        var postData = $(this).serialize();
        $.ajax({
            url:baseURL +"admin/settings/change_social_media",
            type:'post',
            data:postData,
            success:function(){
                SetNotificationModal('social media settings updated');
            }    
        });    
    });
```

Comment: can you show your html code , how did you construct your forms

Comment: have you tried `$('form[name="noteForm"]')` , and `$('form[name="socialMedia"]')`

Comment: are you submitting html forms on the click of any button on page or is there any event on which you submit the form?

Comment: post your html. It cause wrong structure of html with bad select

Answer (score 1):

You have to use the id in the form tag

### This is for your first Form Notifications

```
$('#form1').submit(function(e){
  var postData = $(this).serialize();

  $.ajax({
    url: baseURL + "admin/Settings/ChangeNotificationSettings",
    type: 'post',
    data: postData,
    success:function(data){
      SetNotificationModal('settings successfully updated');
    } ,
    error:function(data){
      alert(data);
    }
  });
  e.preventDefault();
});
```

---

### This is for your second Form SocialMedia

```
<form id="form2"></form>

$('#form2').submit(function(evt){
  evt.preventDefault();
  var postData = $(this).serialize();
  $.ajax({
    url:baseURL +"admin/settings/change_social_media",
    type:'post',
    data:postData,
    success:function(){
     SetNotificationModal('social media settings updated');
    }    
  });    
});
```

Hope this helpful for you

Comment: Doesn't ring a bell

Comment: it's not necessary.

Comment: So can you tell me difference between using name and id for not support submit handler?

Answer (score 0):

First ensure your all forms are separated or closed with  tag.
if you miss any then it will miss behave because of nested form.

> check your Html

```
<html>
    <body>
        <form name='noteForm'>
            <button>NoteForm Submit</button>
        </form>

        <form name='socialMedia'>
            <button>SocialMedia Submit</button>
        </form>  
    </body>
</html>
```

> Your Js

```
$('form[name=noteForm]').submit(function(e){


 var postData = $(this).serialize();

$.ajax({
url: baseURL + "admin/Settings/ChangeNotificationSettings",
type:'post',
data:postData,
success:function(data){

SetNotificationModal('settings successfully updated');

} ,
error:function(data){

alert(data);

}

 });


e.preventDefault();
});
```

////////////second form

```
$('form[name=socialMedia]').submit(function(evt){

 evt.preventDefault();

 var postData = $(this).serialize();

$.ajax({

url:baseURL +"admin/settings/change_social_media",

type:'post',

data:postData,

success:function(){


SetNotificationModal('social media settings updated');

}    
});    
});
```